# Update multiple records using one form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a following situation: `user` has multiple `assets` and each `asset` has one `asset_detail` record.

**Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :asset_detail
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :asset_detail,
  :allow_destroy => false

  attr_accessible # ...
end

class AssetDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :asset

  attr_accessible # ...
end
```

**Controller actions:**

```
def edit
  @user   = current_user
  @assets = Asset.all
end

def update
  @user = current_user
  @user.update_attributes(params["user"])
end
```

**View:**

```
= form_for @user, url: 'update action url' do |f|
  = f.fields_for :assets do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :title 
    = ff.fields_for :asset_detail do |fff|
      = fff.text_field :value
```

The problem is that all the form fields are populated properly but i'm not able to save them. The form is sent without any error but the data is not updated.

Comment: You should check the return value of `@user.update_attributes(params["user"])`...

Answer (score 0):

I think your models should look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :assets_attributes #...
  has_many :assets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets_attributes
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :asset_detail_attrbutes # ...
  has_one :asset_detail
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :asset_detail_attributes,
  :allow_destroy => false
end
```

the reason being, you need to be able to set the attributes via the attributes hash passed to each model.  HTH!

Comment: Just curious - what is the purpose of the asset / asset detail structure?  Is it possible for you to roll the asset detail properties into the asset?

Comment: well, the code i've presented is just a simplified version of system i'm coding and it really needs to be like that ;) Basically, the assets table has multiple types of assets. One of them is `business` and just that one has a relation to asset_details (in fact called `business_details`) .

Comment: Does anything from your form save?  Does user information save, or asset information?  You said update_attributes returns true, so it seems like something would save.  Also: can you take a look at the params[:user] hash and maybe post a sanitized sample here?